# Change numbering in MD Framed

Tags: math-mode, theorems, mdframed

I want to change the numbering using mdframed.

The code is:

```
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{% 
  linecolor=black,
  linewidth=1pt,
  frametitlerule=true,
  frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!20,
  innertopmargin=\topskip,
}
```

If I now use

```
 \mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{definition}{Definition}
 \begin{definition}[Defbla]

 blubb

 \end{definition}
```

It is numbered as Definition 1.
But I want to have it as Definition 1.1 and then 1.2 etc. ...

How can I achieve that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does `\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{definition}{Definition}[section]` work?

Comment: Yeah, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide much information, I am guessing:

1. Load the `amsmath` package.
2. Put `\numberwithin{section}{theorem}` (or `chapter` instead of `section` or ...) in your preamble.

Comment: Thanks that also works :)

Comment: @Armani42 If the answer is useful, then consider accepting it (check mark on the left hand side).

Answer (score 1):

The `\mdtheorem` command is very similar to `\newtheorem`, except that it has a further optional argument:

```latex
\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{definition}{Definition}[section]
\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
```

would define the `definition` environment with numbering subordinate to `section`. Moreover the `theorem` environment is defined, sharing the numbering with `definition`.